# Search Between dates YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii

We have a date example : 2016-05-10, i am trying to get a query from database using this date.

We have 2 tables : publish_at and end_at

```
SELECT * FROM  `news` WHERE end_at <=  '2016-05-11' AND publish_at >=  '2016-05-10'
```

This returns incorrect data as it does not show an event that has publish_at :2016-05-10 and end_at 2016-05-12

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE '2016-05-11' BETWEEN publish_at AND end_at
```

This returns correct item but does not return if date is 10 or 12 only if between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query return correct data since the query reqest all events that publish in the 2016/05/10 or after and ended in the 2016/05/11 or before.

Change the query to

```
Select * from news where end_at between '2016-05-10' and '2016-05-11' or publish_at betweeb '2016-05-10' and '2016-05-12'
```

Comment: Need it daily not over multiples days

Comment: Can understebd your request, whar exactly do you need?

Comment: Basically to get the events between that dates example 
Event 1 : start 05.10 end 05.12
Event 2 : start 05.11 end 05.11
SELECT * FROM  `news` WHERE end_at <=  '2016-05-11' AND publish_at >=  '2016-05-10'

This should display both events

Comment: You toalking about two differnt columns , you need all event between those days? Started or ended?

Comment: aye that will do now to translate that to YII query :)